# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

When i click google oauth button, it gives this errors:

1. Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission,
2. Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Can you help me please ?

my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
 }
}
```

my google auth function:

```
const GoogleAuth = () => {
  const onSuccess = async (response) => {
    var uid = response.profileObj.googleId;
    var username = response.profileObj.name;
    var email = response.profileObj.email;

    if (
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid).get()
    ) {
      await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        uid: uid,
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  const onFailure = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="70189954299-t7a9i8u7lhqm20ji4d3oei88ihef7i5o.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onFailure={onFailure}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        isSignedIn={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is signing in with Google, but is not signing in with Firebase Authentication yet. Only after you sign the user in to Firebase, will the `request.auth` variable in your security rules be populated, so at the moment these security rules correctly reject the request.

To sign in to Firebase with the credentials from Google, call `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)` as shown in the [Advanced: Handle the sign-in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-2) section of the Firebase documentation.

Alternatively, you could use the simpler flow described in [Handle the sign-in flow with the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk), which also handle the calls to the Google sign-in API for you.

Comment: hello. Thanks for the answer. I looked this, and its worked, but i do not understand, i do not use client id in my credential page, why?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but the key is here: `var uid = response.profileObj.googleId;`. The `response.profileObj.googleId` is **not** a Firebase UID, so that comparison never results in any matches. The easiest to see this, is to print both values and you'll see that they're quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I changed my rules config in firebase..It worked for me..

I changed from `allow read, write: if false` to
`allow read, write: if true`

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```